# Open waze deeplink with bicycle mode

Tags: android, waze

I'm trying to create and launch a deeplink based on the navigation apps the user have installed.
More specifically, I trying to figure out which apps have parameters for transportation mode.

For google maps it is possible to add an "mode" parameter like this:

```
val gmmIntentUri =
  Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia&mode=b")
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
startActivity(mapIntent)
```

[source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#kotlin_14)

Does waze have a similar parameter? On [waze's documentation](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks), I was not able to find anything related to that.

Waze doesn't support that yet? Or there is an undocumented parameter or another way to achieve this?!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Waze doesn't support specifying the vehicle type within the deep link. The vehicle mode is something that is part of the user's Waze configuration, which isn't as dynamic as it is in Google Maps. I'm not aware of any undocumented parameters that allow you to override this setting.

Based on the title, I want to mention that Waze has no support for cycling routes. Waze only supports personal vehicles, taxi cars and motorcycles as transport modes. So far, Waze has not expressed any intention to support other transport modes.